# All data needs to be Shifted to the right one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

We had Files sent to us with incomplete/corrupted data missing in a certain column. What happened is that all data to the right was then shifted to the left. Does anybody have a solution for shifting all data right one column?

For reference there are about 13 columns after the empty field. I am looking to shift everything right one column and then write an update statement to fill the column with the appropriate values.

I would include a sample of the data, but it all include PII and so I cannot include it. Currently my solution is to write a series of update statements, but with 1600+ rows I cant help to think there has to be a better way than to update 2 or 3 at a time based on Product ID or Order ID.

Comment: you can always replace PII (y the way,what is it) with some meaningless values and provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Do create ***sample*** data. You can substitute anything sensitive with other characters.

Comment: Honestly, I'm surprised the `INSERT` worked, as presumably your columns have good typing and so a string based value wouldn't have been able to be `INSERT`ed into a date and time based column. In truth, seems you'd be better off just reinserting the data properly to avoid any problems with the data loss you have most certainly already suffered.

Comment: Stop wasting time. The ONLY way to know your data is accurate is to start over with a "good" source file.

Comment: I would definitively reject the files and I would ask for new files that are not corrupted.